# How to properly set up constraints for collection view inside of table view cell (in Interface Builder)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, constraints

So, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949166/proper-way-to-set-constraints-of-collection-view-inside-of-table-view-cell) stack discussion on the same topic but I didn't really find a solution for what I'm trying to do (or none of the solutions worked for me). I've embedded a collection view inside of a table view and set the labels and such accordingly (with correct values, as I've tested by printing labels.text in the console). However, it appears the collection view is automatically sizing my cells to 50 x 50 (defaults), hiding the labels (see image).

I have automatic sizing off, estimate size set to none, and to the best of my knowledge the constraints in the collection view cell do indeed define its size. I tried setting all the heights and widths manually, which appears to do nothing (though it does work for tableview.rowHeight, which for now I've set back to auto sizing as the cell remained 50x50 inside the 325px height row). Any advice is appreciated!

[IMG: what the UI is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXUSJ.png)

[IMG: what the UI looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Pkc.png)

[IMG: collection view cell constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN04s.png)

[IMG: table view attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOOk8.png)

[IMG: table view attributes 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVqoK.png)

[IMG: collection view attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krVEr.png)

[IMG: collection view attributes 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcQC6.png)

[IMG: table view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsw9J.png)

I've done my best to include all pertinent information. Please let me know if more is needed.

Comment: Code would help greatly. Not image links. Maybe something I could duplicate? This site works *because* you can search on Q&A here - nothing in your "Q" really helps.

Comment: My question is about constraints in interface builder. So there’s no real code to reference. The “images” are the code… Also, it’s a bit of work that I can’t ask of you but you can duplicate a collection view inside of a table view, and mess around with the constraints to display an image view and a label with custom sizing.

Comment: I was able to retract my vote to close - still, all I was asking for was clarity - but am unable to remove my downvote without an edit from you. For the record, nothing in you question (maybe in one of your eight image links?) says that you are using IB. I'll remove it it you include that in your question. (?) Here's the thing for me - I do not use IB. It really cannot do anything that code cannot, as opposed to vice-versa. But that's a personal thing. :-) What isn't however, follows....

Comment: A UITableView is simply a special UIScrollView. And a UICollectionView is the same - except that based on what you are targeting it has *more* than it did in two OS versions ago. In terms of constraints? They complicate things - at least in IB. At one point I think the objective with Apple with these views changed from trying to help with constraints (think UIStackView) to nowadays helping with doing data-driven modeling. Is there any chance you could trim down some things? Maybe that can help you find the issue?

Comment: Done, thank you for the feedback. I found a solution that I'll post in answer to this. To be honest from what I've seen constraints in IB clash a lot with the settings for objects in the attributes editor, and when nesting a collection view inside a table view with other items everything becomes a time consuming but solvable mess. It's like the editor doesn't want to coincide with reality, at least for a intermediate developer who barely knows what they're doing ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a handful of solutions to this problem. For me, it was setting the cell size in the attributes editor for the collection view (and in the attributes editor for the collection view cell), while leaving everything with the table view on automatic. The only unfortunate consequence is that the table view row height automatically sizes to the collection view height that you manually set with constraints in interface builder (without said constraint, the table view has no height to go off of). This isn't a problem for me, but it depends on the project.